# Are badge calculations delayed?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges

I haven't received a silver badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821266/what-is-so-special-about-smalltalk) despite 27 upvotes; I've searched the site but been unable to find anything to say that badge calculations may be delayed.

Comment: Jeff - what do you mean "no-repro"? Have I had a silver badge in the 2 days since I wrote this (27 upvote) answer? No, I don't. So why is this marked as "cannot reproduce"?

Comment: I am wondering this as well. After I do something that should earn a badge, it doesn't show up for several minutes at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that often happens causing people to feel as though they didn't earn a badge, is if you've lost a badge (due to a deleted question/answer) or migration, or even just losing the criteria, the badge is not taken away, but the next time you "earn" it, you don't receive, you're just considered no longer in debt. However, looking through your answers, I don't see a likely canidate for where you would have a lost a `good answer` badge.

Comment: Yes - I think I must have had a downvote as onw of my answers is on 24 points.

Answer (score 6):

They can be. Most things like badges, accept rates, and other functions are delayed to some degree as many features are cached and run periodically.

But, Looking at your questions, you do look like you should have 5x Good Answer badges and you have 5. So what is the problem? Did it just show up? It looks like you did recieve a silver badge for the question you linked to.

You answered this question 3 times: [Hidden features of Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/1093363#1093363)  and none of them are over 25 votes. The grand total of your 3 answers is 26, but that wont give a silver badge collectively. Did you happen to include that in your count of how many you should have?

Comment: Oops.  I didn't see that the Scala 26 points came from 3 different answers.  You're right; he deserves and has 5 silver badges.

Comment: In my "this week" stats, I have 1 bronze badge. I have not received a silver badge since Nov 24th yet my answer (which should have a silver badge) is only 2 days old.

Comment: The 3 answers you are referring to are 1). Aeons old and 2) CW. I expect a silver badge from an answer I gave 2 days ago and which now has 27 votes.

Comment: Yah, I can't explain why the badge history doesn't show it (could be cacheing issue for that), but looking at your answers, you should have 5 and you have 5.