# Is there a delay in being awarded the generalist badge?

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119518/generalist-badge-progress-toward-with-improved-sort?userid=256196), I should have been awarded the [Generalist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist), but I haven't.

Presumably if the data is on data explorer, it should be calculated on the live site as awarded.

Assuming the query result is correct (it seems to be), is a delay in awarding expected behaviour?
If not, is there a bug/problem?

Comment: The query is probably wrong. It indicates that I should have received this badge as well, but I haven't.

Comment: There are some delays (see [Are badge calculations delayed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31621/are-badge-calculations-delayed)), and it might be interesting to poke that query on people who have recently been awarded the badge to see if there's anything amiss in the query.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I need to get busy answering some Android and Facebook questions. ...Maybe I'll skip that badge for now.

Comment: And yes, having just gotten the badge (thank you for making me aware of it), there was a delay of 2 hours between the criteria for getting it and the badge being awarded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That query you're running is checking for the top 50 tags rather than the top 40, which is wrong. If you look at the tag ranks next to your score, you'll see that [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) is #47, [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) is #49, and [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) is #50. So those three don't actually count towards your badge.

Comment: Which is a strange mistake, because the query even has `... WITH tags40 AS ( SELECT TOP  50 ...`

Comment: @Juhana Yeah, pretty much *everything* else in the entire query (and the description) references 40. Maybe the author hit the wrong key while typing?

Comment: It looks to me like it may be loosely based on [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/734/generalist-progression), which isn't quite as fancy, but does actually return the correct results.

Comment: According to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/edit/195436), I (userid=993) have 23 tags with `score >= 15`, yet no Generalist badge :(

Comment: @ypercube DBA doesn't yet qualify for the Generalist badge. Your 40th top tag (foreign-key) only has 189 questions. Generalist cannot be awarded on a site until all 40 of the top tags have at least 200 questions.

Comment: @animuson Ah, great, thnx. I did not know that. It certainly isn't in the badge description!